# jQuery Selector .not() isn't working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm stuck why the .not() selector does not affect on validating. This is my HTML form:

```
<input name="Title" id="Title" type="text" />
<div id="ErrorTitle" class="hiddenbox"></div>

<input name="Text" id="Text" type="text" />
<div id="ErrorText" class="hiddenbox"></div>

<input name="Price" id="Price" type="text" />
<div id="ErrorPrice" class="hiddenbox"></div>
```

And this the jquery:

```
if($('#Title').val() == '')
{
    $('#Title').focus();
    ErrorBox('Please enter title', 'ErrorTitle'); // Write message in .hiddenbox
    $('.hiddenbox').not('#ErrorTitle .hiddenbox').hide();
}
else if($('#Text').val() == '')
{
    $('#Text').focus();
    ErrorBox('Please enter text', 'ErrorText'); // Write message in .hiddenbox
    $('.hiddenbox').not('#ErrorText .hiddenbox').hide();
}
else if($('#Price').val() == '')
{
    $('#Price').focus();
    ErrorBox('Please enter price', 'ErrorPrice'); // Write message in .hiddenbox
    $('.hiddenbox').not('#ErrorPrice .hiddenbox').hide();
}
```

When submitting the form no one error message would display!
Do I wrong it?!

Comment: As you are using id selector simply use `not('#ErrorTitle')` there is no need to class selector

Comment: Learn how to use the very basic `CSS` selectors before starting to code. Space denotes hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are wrong in your selector:

```
$(".validate").on('click', valid);
        function valid() {

            if($('#Title').val() == '')
            {

                $('#Title').focus();
                $("#ErrorTitle.hiddenbox").text("errortitle"); // Write message in .hiddenbox
                $("#ErrorTitle.hiddenbox").show();
                $('.hiddenbox').not('#ErrorTitle.hiddenbox').hide();
            }
            else if($('#Text').val() == '')
            {
                $('#Text').focus();
                $("#ErrorText.hiddenbox").text("errortext"); // Write message in .hiddenbox
                $("#ErrorText.hiddenbox").show();
                $('.hiddenbox').not('#ErrorText.hiddenbox').hide();
            }
            else if($('#Price').val() == '')
            {
                $('#Price').focus();
                 $("#ErrorPrice.hiddenbox").text("errorprice"); // Write message in .hiddenbox
                $("#ErrorPrice.hiddenbox").show();
                $('.hiddenbox').not('#ErrorPrice.hiddenbox').hide();
            }
        }
```

Should do the trick.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BenoitNgo/hm128k63/

Comment: That saves me:) Thank you!